# How can I stop an embedded iframe youtube video from playing when a modal is closed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, embed

I have tried the solutions on different posts from SO but none seem to work properly.

I have a modal with an iframe that plays a video, and this seems to work, but I've been trying to stop the video completely when I close the modal but it still seems to attempt to play.

The iframe element

```
<iframe class="modal-iframe" type="text/html" width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO?&controls=0&rel=0&showinfo=0&playlist=VIDEO&loop=1&autoplay=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Opening/Closing events

```
$(".custom-modal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function (e) {

var iframe = $('#' + e.target.id).find("iframe");

if (iframe.attr("src") && iframe.attr('src').indexOf('autoplay') != -1) {
                var newURL = iframe.attr('src').substring(0, iframe.attr('src').length - 11);
                iframe.attr('src', newURL);
}

})


$('.custom-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
var iframe = $('#' + e.target.id).find("iframe");
if (iframe) {
        var videoSrc = iframe.attr("src");
        iframe.attr("src", videoSrc+"&autoplay=1");
}
});
```

This seems to work to some extent and the `autoplay` tag is appended/removed correctly, however for some reason when the modal is closed, the video still seems to try and play again as I get errors in the console (it doesn't actually manage to play but I can see this being a problem when I have multiple videos in different modals)

[image]
[image]

So the autoplay tag is removed when the modal is closed, but this thread still seems to exist for the video.

How can I stop the video completely so it doesn't send any more requests when the modal is closed?

---

So I think I've found the problem. The iframe is loaded onto the main page when the modal is opened, and it is always present in the background. I have tried removing the iframe via `remove()` and this works and stops the errors but the iframe then does not load a second time when the modal is re-opened.

I need a solution to unload the iframe, but still allow it to be reloaded when the modal is opened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created two video urls, one with autoplay and one without and then just toggled between two and it is working for me :

```
var video = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/ogfYd705cRs";
var autoVideo = video + "?modestbranding=1&rel=0&controls=0&showinfo=0&html5=1&autoplay=1";

$(".custom-modal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function (e) {
  var iframe = $('#' + e.target.id).find("iframe");
  iframe.attr("src", video);
})

$(".custom-modal").on("show.bs.modal", function (e) {
  var iframe = $('#' + e.target.id).find("iframe");
  iframe.attr("src", autoVideo);
});
```

So why not storing video URL in a data attribute ?

```
<iframe class="modal-iframe" type="text/html" width="640" height="360" src="" data-video="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ogfYd705cRs" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

and then get video URLs inside the functions :

```
$(".custom-modal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function (e) {
    var iframe = $('#' + e.target.id).find("iframe");
    var video = iframe.attr("data-video");
    iframe.attr("src", video);
})

$('.custom-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var iframe = $('#' + e.target.id).find("iframe");
    var autoVideo = iframe.attr("data-video") + "?modestbranding=1&rel=0&controls=0&showinfo=0&html5=1&autoplay=1";
    iframe.attr("src", autoVideo);
});
```

And for multiple videos per modal put video URL on anchors you use for opening modals:

```
<a href="modals/somemodal.html" class="video-anchor" data-target="#modal1" data-video="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ogfYd705cRs" data-toggle="modal">
```

and instead listening for modal open listen for anchor click and :

```
$(".video-anchor").click(function () {
  var modal = $(this).data("target");
  var video = $(this).attr("data-video");
  var autoVideo = video + "?modestbranding=1&rel=0&controls=0&showinfo=0&html5=1&autoplay=1";
  $(modal + ' iframe').attr('src', autoVideo);
});
```

and when modal closes it is not important what we set as src so :

```
$(".custom-modal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function (e) {
  var iframe = $('#' + e.target.id).find("iframe");
  iframe.attr("src", "");
})
```

Comment: How does this work for multiple videos? I may have 2-3 videos per modal, and 5 modals that can be opened on the page. Would I not have to create variables for each link?

Comment: how you open the modals ?

Comment: Using `<a href="modals/somemodal.html" data-target="#modal1" data-toggle="modal">` and the modal content is within `somemodal.html`

Comment: But yes your solution for replacing the autoplay is much better. I'll try it now.

Comment: This still doesn't handle multiple per modal does it? i.e my `#modal1` or `somemodal.html` will have multiple iframes. Using your first example both videos are set to the same link. Also this still doesn't solve the problem of the iframe being present (it's still trying to play even though it's closed)

Comment: You want multiple videos per modal at the same time or different videos inside a modal when user clicks on different anchors ? The last example is for showing different videos inside one modal but not at the same time. You want to play multiple videos together ? (Please create a fiddle/snippet of your current code otherwise it would be really hard to understand your needs)

Comment: Yes multiple videos in the same modal, playing at the same time. Each modal can have multiple videos, and the videos will be different. When the modal closes I want all of the videos to stop playing so there is no errors in the console or any additional requests to youtube. I will try to create a fiddle now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179253/discussion-between-r3zaxd1-and-jjmcc).

Comment: I have accepted this answer as it actually gave me the solution to the problem I was having, even if it was unintentional. The solution was to set the iframe's `src` to nothing or `""`, meaning the iframe is destroyed, but can still be loaded again when the modal is re-opened. Prior to this, I was keep the iframe's `src` as the video's url which meant that the iframe was still performing actions in the background even if the modal was closed.